# Como simular um pressionamento de teclas com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de simular pressionamento de teclas com o jQuery.

Por exemplo, ao clicar em um botão, simular que as teclas "down" e "left" foram pressionadas, como se o usuário tivesse teclado elas.

```
 $(document).on('click', function (){
       // Simule pressionar as teclas 'down' e 'left' do teclado           
 });
```

Tem como fazer isso? Com jQuery, de preferência.

Para quem está confuso, acho que o termo utilizado nesse tipo de operação (geralmente por gamers) é `bot` (robô) para pressionamento de teclas.

Comment: Haters gonna hatters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode criar o evento e acioná-lo em seguida.

```
var teclaEsquerda = jQuery.Event("keypress");
teclaEsquerda.ctrlKey = false;
teclaEsquerda.which = 37; //Código da tecla - seta esquerda

$("botao").trigger(teclaEsquerda);
```

Código das outras setas:

- Para cima: 38
- Para baixo: 40
- Direita: 39

Comment: Valeu, era isso  mesmo +1

Comment: Entenda a minha resposta apenas como complemento, mas a sua resolve a questão :)

Answer (score 4):

Vou responder a minha pergunta, mas não levem a mal. Considerem apenas como complemento.

Como já foi dito pelo @PedroCamaraJunior em sua excelente resposta, você pode o `jQuery.Event` para criar um evento.

Quando precisei fazer isso, criei uma extensão para o jQuery, para que isso funcionasse de maneira mais reutilizável.

Abaixo o código:

```
(function ($){

    $.fn.triggerKeyPress = function (keys)
    {
        var keydownEvent = $.Event("keydown");

        var $self = this;

        $.each(keys, function(index, value) {

            var simulatedKey = $.extend({}, keydownEvent, {which: value, keyCode: value});

            $self.trigger(simulatedKey);
        });

    }

})( jQuery );
```

Para usar, basta escolher o elemento onde deseja simular as teclas:

```
$('body').triggerKeyPress([37, 40])
```