# Como cancelar eventos como keyPress, keyDown, ... de uma tecla e ativar os mesmos em uma outra

Tags: javascript

Eu jogo um jogo flash no browser a bastante tempo, e recentemente adquiri um notebook com um teclado bem diferente do anterior e fiquei pensando se poderia ter um script em Javascript que eu executasse no console que 'alterasse' as teclas. Por exemplo, quando eu pressionar as teclas `WSAD` seria como se eu tivesse pressionado as teclas das setas.

Só para ilustrar...

```
trocar(A, B) {

cancelarEventoDe(A);

ativarEventoDe(B);

}
```

Comment: Eu creio que o Flash toma conta dos eventos. Então eu creio que, enquanto o foco estiver no componente Flash, todo e qualquer JavaScript de gerenciamento de UI é ignorado. Não posso falar com certeza, entretanto.

Comment: Encontrei outro tópico que possivelmente resolve meu problema, não posso testar agora. É um script com jQuery, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126326/como-simular-um-pressionamento-de-teclas-com-jquery